# Can not find the cached files (through flutter_cache_manager) on device

Tags: flutter, dart, caching

I am using this code to cache files on my local storage:

`var audioFile = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile('fileUrl');`

I need to physically access the file to see if the user can access it from the file manager. When I run the app, the files are being cached. But I can not find the path where the files are cached on the device.

This is the address that I get on debug mode:
"/data/user/0/{my_package_name}/cache/libCachedImageData/3a65ece0-5366-11eb-91e0-0f0ba53cd292.mp4"

But there is no such path on my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a path to a "hiden" folders on your device. You can navigate to this path with root privileges or get (and navigate) the data by tutorials like [this](https://margaretmz.medium.com/how-to-access-private-data-on-android-a0841a11b487). Also you can find this folders without any permissions on Android emulator from File Explorer tab in Android Studio.